# Keep track of which UDP socket receives packets

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm currently using NodeJS and I want to create an array of multiple udp4 sockets. It is important to me which socket is receiving a message, so I'm trying to store everything as following:

```
var sockets = [];

function startSocket(socketObject) {
    socketObject.HandleIncomingPacket = function(buffer, header) {
        if(header.address === this.ip) {
            console.log("ID: "+this.id+" | right IP");
        }else{
            console.log("ID: "+this.id+" | wrong IP. IP expected: "+this.ip+", given: "+header.address);
        }
    }

    socketObject.socket = dgram.createSocket("udp4");
    socketObject.socket.on("message", socketObject.HandleIncomingPacket);
    socketObject.socket.bind(socketObject.port);
    sockets[socketObject.id] = socketObject;
}
```

Calling the function with object `{ip: "127.0.0.1", port: 1234}` works fine (read: no errors), but on incoming packets I receive the following output: `ID: undefined | wrong IP. IP expected: undefined, given: 127.0.0.1`

How come `this` is undefined in this context? Is it even possible to do anything like I am trying to do now? I'm probably missing out on something.

Comment: Is this even valid JavaScript?  I don't see how this would run.

Comment: I call the function `startSocket` with the object as specified in my question, and it runs. I don't see how this is invalid?

Comment: `socketObject.HandleIncomingPacket(buffer, header) {` doesn't make much sense - it looks like you're trying to define a function, but there's no `function` keyword.

Comment: Excuse me, I accidentally removed too much when copy pasting. Fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that using `bind()` I get the result I need.